# Wordpress smtp mail from address is not working

Tags: wordpress, smtp, smtpclient

i am using `wp_mail_smtp` for sending mail in WordPress and its working fine expect one thing i have define the from email : **abc@mysite.com** and from name: my site and  username password for smtp authentication is : **someemail@example.com** and password of my mail id.

now problem is that when i sending the mail than i receive mail header like

mysite< someemail@example.com > and it should be mysite< abc@mysite.com > i have also set the filter for from name and from mail like below code

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');
function new_mail_from($old) {
    return 'abc@mysite.com';
}
function new_mail_from_name($old) {
    return 'mysite.com';
}
```

and my mail code is

```
$headers = 'From: abc@mysite.com ' . "\r\n";
$to = "admin@test.com"
$send_subject = "Mail Subject"
$message .= "Some message";
wp_mail( $to, $send_subject, $message,$headers );
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong so that i can receive mail header correctly

Thanks

Comment: please post how you are receiving the email, and the function which responsible for the sending email

Comment: This is simple wp_mail function which seding mail and normal parameters

Comment: You can configure an SMTP server for `wp_mail()` without the need for a plugin: https://gist.github.com/butlerblog/c5c5eae5ace5bdaefb5d

Comment: I know how to use SMTP I am using how to change received mail header in Gmail message header mysite< someemail@example.com > and it should be mysite< abc@mysite.com >. right now  mail showing  the SMTP authenticated mail but I want it shows my site name